# How to create local post on google my business page using php

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I need to create a local host using google client api . I wrote following code to crate local post.

```
$service = new Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
$callToAction = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_CallToAction();
$callToAction->setActionType('LEARN_MORE');
$callToAction->setUrl('localhost.com');
$mediaItem = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_MediaItem();
$mediaItem->setMediaFormat('PHOTO');
$mediaItem->setSourceUrl('https://www.theanthem.com/images/usps_eddm_postcards.jpg');
$localPost = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_LocalPost();
$localPost->setLanguageCode('en-US');
$localPost->setSummary('Just a summary');
$localPost->setCallToAction($callToAction);
$localPost->setMedia($mediaItem);
$parent = sprintf('accounts/%d/locations/%d',
'116633170334837786295',
'8830395735149945322'
);
$service->accounts_locations_localPosts->create($parent, $localPost);
```

But Unfortunately  I got following error.

> My Error: Message: Error calling POST
>   https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/9223372036854775807/locations/8830395735149945322/localPosts:
>   (400) Request contains an invalid argument.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

> create refresh token

```
 $request_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
 $refresh_token = "*** Refresf Token ***";
 $params = [
            'client_id'     => "***your client id***",
            'client_secret' => "***your clinet secret id***",
            'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
            'grant_type'    => "refresh_token"
          ];
  $curl = curl_init($request_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  $postData = "";
  //This is needed to properly form post the credentials object
  foreach($params as $k => $v) {
    $postData .= $k . '='.urlencode($v).'&';
  }
  $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
  $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
  $response = (array) json_decode( $json_response );
  $myaccess_token = $response['access_token'];
```

> And create Post

```
$location = 'accounts/accoutid/locations/location id';
$api_end_point_url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/'.$location.'/localPosts';
$postfields = array(
'topicType' => "STANDARD",
'languageCode' => "en_US",
'summary' => 'test post 123',
);
$data_string = json_encode($postfields); 
$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_end_point_url);      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $myaccess_token,'Content-Type: application/json'));
$data1 = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
$http_code1 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: I tried code to post data in to Google My Business but some how it's not working and get me Error.
Creating/Updating a local post is not authorized for this location.
Error code 403
Can you please help me on that?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue, "Creating/Updating a local post is not authorized for this location"? Is it required that your location should be verified?

Answer (score 1):

I did a request using almost this same code, but using the V2 API which returns better errors sometimes...It says the topic type is missing:

```
 "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
        "errorDetails": [
          {
            "code": 2,
            "field": "topic_type",
            "message": "Topic type is required for post creation."
          }
        ]
```